# PHP/AJAX/SQL - how to keep chatroom userlist updated reliably, feasibly?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I've managed to get a chatroom up and running pretty well using PHP, JavaScript, AJAX, SQL, but not JQuery or anything else. I'm using session variables to keep users persistent automatically, even for guests passing through, because I want the chatroom on the front page. (It's www.chatbae.com if you're curious.)

The problem is, the persistent user records stick around even after the guest has left the room, build up, and clutter the user list.

There are two SQL tables of relevance for this issue -

---

lastActivity table (monitors last activity in each room) with columns:

- roomname (name of this chatroom)
- counter (index of last message in a "chatRecords" table)
- userDT (dateTime of last addition to user list)
- parentFolder (parent folder on server - not relevant here)
- isHidden (visible on room list? not relevant here)

---

activeUsers table (records the users in all chatrooms)
Relevant columns:

- session_id (unique session ID for the user)
- username (username, random if user is a guest)
- isReg (is the user registered?)
- roomname (name of the room the user is in)
- counter (index of last comment received from 'chatRecords' table)
- userDT (dateTime of last time the userlist was updated for this user)
- roomlistChanged (boolean; is this user notified of recent roomlist
  change?)
- lastActivity (dateTime of last comment or change to username)

---

The activeUsers table contains the problem, because there are plenty of ways users can leave the chatroom without explicitly "telling me".

I've considered setting up Javascript timers, to boot the user from chat if they don't queryChat for awhile. (queryChat occurs every 3 seconds to grab new chatroom comments and other updates.) However, this timer will be gone because it's clientside, and the client will have left the room.

I've also considered tying the lastActivity column to the queryChats function, but that implies that every user will update that one table every 3 seconds which sounds infeasible. (I've actually tried it anyway to see what happens, but the page freezes, I think.)

A possible workable solution would be to set up a flag on the server that resets with every five minutes, maybe a global PHP timer mechanic, that checks all users and boots those that have been inactive for awhile.

The problem here is that if the timer is too long, you'll have ghost users (i.e. that have already left) in the chatroom for a long time, but if the timer is too short, users will be frustrated from feeling like they have to talk quickly to avoid being booted.

I'm just not sure how a "real" chatroom manages userlists. Is there an obvious solution I'm missing?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can do a "ping" check to all the users in `activeUsers` and than you can check if the user is responding or something and if not, delete it from the database. I don't know exactly how, but this can in jQuery Ajax and PHP.

Comment: if you keep a constant connection, you'll know the instant a user leaves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your current architecture the best way would be a combination of frontend timers and a backend activity time filter.

You need a timer on the frontend that pings the server every 3 to 5 seconds (tune dependant on how "accurate" you need it, the longer between pings the better). Store the current time as the users last activity (or invent a new column if last activity means something more specific in your app), and also send back an active users list so that stays up to date.

On the backend, just put a filter on any "active users" type query that filters out anyone that hasnt pinged in the past 5 seconds.

You can use a crontab task every minute to remove dead users from any active user tables (so your filter has to do less filtering), or use the dirty `if(mt_rand(0,100) === 42)` trick to every once in a while run a cleanup inside your pinger script.

Obviously your not gong to get the performance of real chat applications, but theres some obvious things you can do with this that would increase its performance.

> Note: "Real" chat applications at a basic level operate in much the
>   same way, they just get performance benefits from having websockets
>   and usually a much better language choice for this type of
>   application. They also suffer from ghost users if their frontend apps
>   close down ungracefully and have to rely on pings

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a Javascript on the client to verify the activity with an interval `WindowTimers.setInterval()`: 
[JavaScript Interval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) to verify and compare your last activity value with the current time. And finally on the server side have a PHP method that definitely boots the user if the `WindowTimers.setInterval()` doesn't send a response in a window of time